# Can't solve problems with ESLint in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have installed ESLint extension, then initialized on my local project, solved ESLint problems. No more problems appeared, started application, but failed to compile, all the problems reappeared.
what should i do? in vscode i have no problems but in browser i have a lot of problems.[problems window in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keAGz.png)[browser in localhost after i start the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30J26.png)

Comment: ensure vscode is set to respect your line endings of the file.

Comment: i did, and i changed every line ending, when i started the app i got that errors again. i saved the changes, i added the changes to git, but errors are still there

Comment: @LeoMatei do you have an [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file? [Here's what mine looks like for VSCode](https://pastebin.com/RaP2JGPu).

Comment: @Andy i solved the problem by editing eslintrc.json and package.json, now it works properly

Comment: You should add the solution to your problem as an answer for future visitors to the site. @LeoMatei

Answer (score 0):

updated .eslintrc.json then solved the problems again. this time when i compile i get no errors!

{
"parserOptions": {
"ecmaVersion": 6,
"ecmaFeatures": {
"jsx": true
},
"sourceType": "module"
},

"settings": {
"react": {
"version": "detect"
}
},

"plugins": [
"react"
],

"rules": {
"react/jsx-no-bind": ["error", {
"allowArrowFunctions": true,
"allowBind": false,
"ignoreRefs": true
}],
"react/no-did-update-set-state": "error",
"react/no-unknown-property": "error",
"react/no-unused-prop-types": "error",
"react/prop-types": "error",
"react/react-in-jsx-scope": "error"
}
}